Controls going invisible when changing background color of canvas in WinUI 3
I've recently started to use WinUI 3 and have an issue with changing the backcolor of a canvas. Coming from WPF, I was used that simply changing the Background property works. This however, results in everything inside the canvas becoming invisible until clicked or otherwise interacted with. When no background property is set, everything works fine, except the background is colored based on my windows design setting, which is not what I want. This doesn't only affect canvasses, but also stackpanels, grids and so on.

When using a background however, like Background="White", the effect is the following. You can see that my cursor is the text symbol, indicating that the textbox is still there and it shows up when clicked, it's invisible though when not interacted with. Same goes for buttons and other controls.

I'm new to WinUI 3 as mentioned, so there might be a crucial thing that I'm missing. Please let me know if that's the point. Otherwise, is this somehow fixable? Thank you.
Edit: Not sure how I even forgot that, but here's the code:
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Background="White">
            <TextBox Width="200" Height="50" Canvas.Top="300" Canvas.Left="300" Visibility="Visible"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>


You could modify the default Style and ControlTemplate to give the control a unique appearance. The default style, template, and resources that define the look of the control are included in the generic.xaml file.
When I use the default style and change the background color of the canvas, controls remain visible.

For design purposes, generic.xaml is installed with the WinUI (Microsoft.UI.Xaml) NuGet package. By default, this location is \Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml\<version>\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.UI.Xaml\Themes\generic.xaml. Styles and resources from different versions of WinUI might have different values.
